# Kinect speech recognition slow

Tags: speech-recognition, kinect

I'm playing with the Kinect speech recognition features, and noticed that there is a frustrating latency that makes it borderline unusable.  This is even for the case when there are only a handful of words it needs to recognize (you have to tell it via a grammar what words to look for).  I see this latency even on the sample MS provides, AND on the video MS themselves use to promote the technology (the turtle example).

Does anyone know if there are some obvious configuration settings I'm missing here?  Must be something ditzy.

aside: I can't ask this question on the msdn forums for kinect because the forums site is not working me - a weird infinite redirect loop after I log in... seems to affect lots of people, but they can't report it on the forums because they can't ask questions because of the issue itself.

Comment: The Kinect only serves as a microphone, Microsoft Speech SDK is what is actually doing all the work.  What type of computer are you using?  Have you tried it on others?  I've been working with the Speech SDK for a few months and notice a little lag (not unusable) on my Intel i5 laptop, and notice much quick responses when I have it on a snappier computer.

Comment: thanks for that info.  good to know.  how does the lag you are seeing compare to the lag in this video from ms (the "turtle" example)?   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/tutorials/tutorialsdesc.aspx?tutorialid=Tutorial3

Comment: I'd say it about on par on my laptop -- as I see about 1 second delay in there overall.  Sometimes the turtle takes a little longer ('forward' was a slow react) but faster others ('turn right' snapped pretty quickly).  My app has a keyword I have to say before issuing a command... "Floyd" (yes, really) - pause - "Map View".  During that pause a confirmation comes up and lists the commands I can say -- with 1 second being the rough high water mark.  The second command I issue usually hits pretty quick, but I can sometimes take a breath before it goes through.  What is your goal for the speech?

Comment: :)  all very good info.  duh on this probably being more to do with the external speech engine rather than the kinect, which is just being the microphone, I guess... well, though, the kinect have 4 mics that is does some processing on to remove ambient noise, etc.  my goal is not to have that more-than-long-enough-delay-to-be-irritating when you're telling it something "simple" like a single number

Comment: Can you provide a sample use case for what you want to do, and perhaps some sample code of how you are currently going about it?